# Connected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose $\Delta(G) + \delta(G) \geq n-1$. Can we conclude that $G$ is connected?

Comment: I presume $n$ is the number of vertices, and $\Delta(G)$
and $\delta(G)$ are respectively the maximum and minimum
vertex-degrees of the graph $G$?

Comment: Yes Robin you are correct.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. Suppose that $V(G)$ can be split into two sets $A$ and $B$ of respective sizes $a \geq b \geq 1$, and no edges between the two sets.  Since vertices in $A$ (resp. $B$) have degree at most $a-1$ (resp. $b-1$), we see that $\Delta(G) \leq a-1$ and $\delta(G) \leq b-1$. So $\Delta(G) + \delta(G) \leq a+b-2 = n-2$.

Comment: It's really nice to see three completely different solutions. I really like JBL's solution since it gives much more positive information. Mine shows in addition that the result is optimal.

Answer (score 7):

We can do this without inducting on the size of the graph: choose a vertex $v$ of degree $\Delta$ and any other vertex $w$ of degree $d \geq n - 1 - \Delta$.  Either $w$ is adjacent to $v$ or, by the pigeonhole principle, they have a common neighbor among the other $n - 2$ vertices.  So not only is the graph connected but it's actually of diameter at most 4.

Answer (score 5):

Take a vertex $v$ of maximum degree, then delete a vertex $w$ not adjacent to $v$.

Comment: Nitpick.  If $w$ does not exist, then G is clearly connected, so there is no need to apply induction.  